# Tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

for the list of tuples below:

```
x= [('a',1),('b', 2)]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
x_1 = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2}
```

if i use dict(x), the dict becomes unordered, i want it in the exact same order.
really need this for my course work, please help fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if order must be preserved:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> x= [('a',1),('b', 2)]
>>> x_1 = OrderedDict(x)
>>> for key in x_1:
...     print(key)
... 
a
b
```

Comment: That works perfectly until i print out the keys as well as the values, programs says, ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
i used this because i want them to be on the same line:    
     for key, vlaues in x_1:
        print(key,values)

Comment: @PratyushKhurana, `x_1.items()` returns both `key` and `value`, simple itertion over `x_1` returns only `key`. So use `for key, values in x_1: print(key,values)` instead.

Comment: @PratyushKhurana: sounds like you want to iterate over `x_1.items()` instead then.

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD: you actually forgot to include `.items()` in your sample. :-P

Comment: It finally worked! :D Thank you so much for your quick responses guys! And sorry for taking up your time :p

Answer (score 0):

You need `collections.ordereddict`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> x= [('a',1),('b', 2)]
>>> x = OrderedDict(x)
>>> x
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])  # Order is preserved
```

This doesn't look like python dictionary but it actually is as can be seen from below examples:

```
>>> x['a']  
1
>>> x['b']
2
>>> for key,val in x.items():
...    print(key,val)
... 
a 1
b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, **dictionary in Python (or associative array)** is a **disordered** data structure, which stores *key-value* data and allows user has fast way to extract *value* by given *key*, to add a new pair *key-value* or remove an existing pair. This data structure must be disordered to make all necessary algorithms working quickly.

For more information about dictionary, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

If you do need to use order of keys, I would recommend you create dictionary and list or keys separately. It will take more memory, but will work faster, generally.

```
x = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]

dct = dict(x) # dictionary
kys = zip(*x)[0] # tuple of keys
```

Good luck!